# Recurrence relation help?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

$$t(n)=\begin{cases}n&\text{if }n=0,1,2,\text{ or }3\\t(n-1)+t(n-3)-t(n-4)&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases} $$
Express your answer as simply using the theta notation.

I don't know where to go with this.

$$t(n) - t(n-1) - t(n-3) + t(n-4) = 0$$

Is the characteristic polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - x +1 = 0$?

Comment: Hint: Use [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Comment: @Bartek: Not for this one...

Comment: Right, stupid me, its more like Fib numbers.

Comment: Can you help me Raphael instead of sending me to that?

Comment: There's a readable explanation of how to find solutions to these "linear homogeneous recurrence relations with constant coefficients" [here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/8-3.pdf).

Comment: That's way more useful than Raphael's. Now I'm curious if my characteristic equation is correct? What throws me off is that mine jumps from n-1 to n-3. Does that mean anything?

Comment: If mine is correct then my answers are (x-1)(x-1)(x+1)=0

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $x^4-x^3-x-1$ (the $+t(n-4)$ should be $-t(n-4)$), which can be factored as $(x^2+1)(x^2-x-1)$.

Comment: Why should it be -t(n-4) when It was negative to begin with and I moved it to the other side? My mistake I wrote the problem wrong and edited it now. Anyways I don't know how to work with that characteristic polynomial. Are the solutions all complex?

Comment: Well working it  out it gave me 2 real and 2 complex solutions.